# Objective C- How to add digits in a number?

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, digits

How do I add the digits in a particular number for example if the number is 3234 the result should be 3+2+3+4 = 12?

Comment: not an iPhone or objective-c problem... just algorithm

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something along the lines of this should do it:

```
int val = 3234;

int sum = 0;
while (val != 0) {
    sum += (val % 10);
    val = val / 10;
}

// Now use sum.
```

For continued adding until you get a single digit:

```
int val = 3234;

int sum = val;
while (sum > 9) {
    val = sum;
    sum = 0;
    while (val != 0) {
        sum += (val % 10);
        val = val / 10;
    }
}

// Now use sum.
```

Note that both of these are destructive to the original `val` value. If you want to preserve it, you should make a copy or do this in a function so the original is kept.

Comment: missing semicolon

sum += (val % 10);

Comment: thanks! now if I want to iterate this process until I get a single digit no from 1 to 9 how to do it.

Comment: for example 3+2++3+4=12 1+2 = 3. 3 shoiuld be the result.

Comment: while (len > 1) {
  sum=0;
  while (val != 0 ) {
   sum += (val % 10);
   val = val / 10;
   
  }
  val=sum;
  temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sum ];
  len=[temp length];
  
 }

Comment: Thanks! I could have done this thing so easily instead of finding the length and writing all that code to convert int to string.

Answer (score 2):

Hope it is not your homework !

```
int sum = 0;
while (value!=0) {
  sum += value % 10;
  value = value / 10;
}
```

Comment: actually i have an idea about how to do this in php, but am unable to do this in objective c.

Comment: actually my algo in php sort of treats the number as an array. like number[0], number[1] and uses for each to add all the digits.